# iOS : device is hanging while running an intensive computing task

Tags: ios, load, cpu, sleep

I have designed an application which sometimes needs to make intensive computing (inside a loop), that loads cpu heavily during few tenths of seconds. I launch a UIAlertView to display a message, something like: "please wait for few seconds".
My problem is that during this period the App is not responsive at all, and the UIAlertView itself cannot be dismissed by user. This is not a major issue but not fair for the user. But it could become a real problem if I was to implement some kind of cancel button.
How can I solve this ? For example is there some sleep command that I could use inside my computing loop when detecting too much cpu load ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't perform CPU intensive operations on the main thread - as it will impact the app responsiveness as you have seen.  You can use a [dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2) queue to perform the task on another thread.

There is more detail in the Apple guide I linked to, but in general you can use something like -

```
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
    [self performIntensiveTask];
});
```

If necessary, you may need to know when your intensive task has completed.  You could use an `NSNotification` to do this or you could just update your UI elements - if you choose the second be aware that you should only update UI elements on the main thread so you would have -

```
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
    [self performIntensiveTask];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateUI];
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. One consequence is that I have now to prevent the user from launching other tasks waiting for this one to complete, but this is minor issue. Thus I am completely satisfied with the answer. Thanks for this